# How can I connect NSSearchField to my NSTableViewDataSource?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nssearchfield

Most of the examples that I saw only connects `NSSearchField` to an `NSArrayController`.  The problem is that I populated my `NSTableView` using `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol.  I want my `NSSearchField` to search on the given `NSTableView`.  Is there any way that I can do that or should I convert my datasource into an `NSArray` Controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an `NSSearchField` without an array controller but you are responsible for handling the search and update of the table view.

Have your data source class respond to the `‑controlTextDidChange:` and/or the `‑controlTextDidEndEditing:` delegate methods of `NSControl` (`NSSearchField` is a subclass of `NSControl`) and in those delegate method do your search and update the table accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This can actually solve the problem but the client wants to use apple's zero code searching using the NSSearchfield.  What I did was to convert my datasource into an NSArray controller.  Thanks again for the help.